# Sidekick Cloud build - iOS - Cloud messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript, sidekick

I'm pretty new in app development, that's why I'm using Cloud Builds with Nativescript Sidekick.

I have well installed/setup Firebase, everything works for Android, but for iOS, I don't get messages. Nativescript's Firebase plugin from Eddy Verbruggen says that you must must enable push notifications from xcode to receive messages.

NB : In firebase, in my ios App (of firebase), my device is well detected, but I'm not receiving anything.

I don't know how to have an .xcodeproj from a cloud build. Do you know how to fix this ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using cloud builds, you may enable the Cloud Messaging from Developer Portal. You must have a paid Apple Developer Account to do so, login to https://developer.apple.com/ and then navigate to [Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) section, edit your app identifier to include **Push Notifications** Capabilities.

Then navigate to [Keys](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list) section, create a auth key and add the generated key to your Firebase iOS app. Detailed instructions can be found at [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

I hope you already configured the entitlement file as described in the [plugin docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md#ios).

Comment: Hi Manoj, many thanks (again) for your help.

I well created a key for push, (p8 file), but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Besides, do I need to open my app in Xcode to enable Push notifications, and how to do it ?

Comment: You don't have to open Xcode. I have already mentioned where you would upload the keys in Firebase, please read carefully.